# OpenCL 2.0 on nVIDIA Graphics cards

Tags: opencl

I want to  use OpenCL 2.0 because it benefit from very nice features like Creating Sub Devices, or Shared Virtual Memory but my OpenCL header files which are coming out with nvidia cuda does not have the opencl 2.0 functions. Is there any way to use OpenCL 2.0 on my nvidia gpus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not - NVIDIA does not currently support OpenCL 2.0, and they have not yet given any timeframe for doing so.

Comment: It is really sad for me. Because OpenCL 2.0 has very cool features to use all of the computing resources and in my company we only have nvidia graphic cards. It is really sad that we cannot use those cool features of OpenCL 2.0 :(

Comment: They did announce at GTC last week that the driver version 349 coming out next month will have OpenCL 1.2 support, and this is because they listened to developers. So continued developer pressure could result in OpenCL 2.0 support. So be heard.

Comment: @Dithermaster Indeed, and their current drivers also show some signs of OpenCL 2.0 features - some SVM strings are present, and the OpenCL 2.0 functions `work_group_any` and `work_group_all` are actually implemented and work just fine.

Comment: @jprice I posted a question that is a spin off of your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31208501/568785 Since you knew about the work group functions already implemented, are you aware of any other features implemented before official 2.0 support?

Answer (score 8):

In the 378.66 drivers NVIDIA claims limited support of OpenCL 2.0 for evaluation purposes. Look at page 10 of release notes http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/378.66/378.66-win10-win8-win7-desktop-release-notes.pdf

Comment: driver v430 still don't have OpenCL 2.0. Personally I am going to buy competitors GPU from now on.

Comment: How did you check it? Through API call through querying CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION? If so - yes they still return 1.2, but you can use OpenCL 2 api by dynamically loading updated functions from ICD (I mean clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties) and supplying key "-cl-std=CL2.0" as option when calling clBuildProgram. That is the way it works in still 'evaluation mode' not for 'production code'.